# ZMQ socket connect timeout

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm trying to connect a socket to an endpoint until the socket receives data from that endpoint. This is because the endpoint might not exist at that time.

Currently the connect stalls, i'm guessing because it can't resolve the hostname and that takes a while.

Is there any way to set a timeout on a socket connect?

```
import zmq
import time

endpoint = 'tcp://doesnt_exist:12345'

ctx = zmq.Context.instance()
s = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)

t = time.time()
try:
    s.connect(endpoint)
except Exception:
    pass

print time.time() - t
```

Comment: Please show the relevant portions of your code. When you interrupt the code, what is the stack trace? If you're using hostnames, as you mention, can you resolve the hostname outside of your program (in the console, for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you provide a host name to `connect`, ZeroMQ uses synchronous DNS resolution via a call to `getaddrinfo`, which is why you see the `connect` call blocking.

If you really need to `connect` in controllable way, I suggest you do DNS resolve on your own, using one of the asynchronous DNS resolvers already available for Python (check [this example based on pyuc/pycares](https://github.com/saghul/pycares/blob/master/examples/cares-resolver.py)).

Also see my reply to [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171564/zeromq-connect-is-blocking).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the connection, but the DNS lookup. The blocking is done at the OS level, on the `gethostbyname` call.

Since the timeout is controlled by the OS, working around it [is hard](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/790534) (but feasible). My suggestion is that you simply hardcode the IP