# ZeroMQ connect is blocking

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, zeromq

If a connection endpoint is an IP like tcp://192.168.0.2:9876, Socket.connect will return instantaneously. However, if the endpoint contains a DNS name like tcp://server.local.:9876 Socket.connect seems to block until server.local. is resolved, and eventually fails and raises a zmq.error.ZMQError exception if the the name cannot be resolved.

Is there a way to connect in an non blocking way ?

Comment: This is exactly the same question as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21169031), posted two hours ago

Answer (score 3):

DNS hostname resolution is done in a synchronous way inside [zmq::socket_base_t::connect](https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq4-x/blob/master/src/socket_base.cpp#L535):

```
//  Resolve address (if needed by the protocol)
if (protocol == "tcp") {
    paddr->resolved.tcp_addr = new (std::nothrow) tcp_address_t ();
    alloc_assert (paddr->resolved.tcp_addr);
    int rc = paddr->resolved.tcp_addr->resolve (
        address.c_str (), false, options.ipv6);
    if (rc != 0) {
        delete paddr;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Therefore it seems you have no other choice but do your own async DNS resolution, then pass the resolved address to ZeroMQ.

You may find useful the following [resolver example](https://github.com/saghul/pycares/blob/master/examples/cares-resolver.py). It is based on pyuv/pycares and looks pretty nice.